# when i use Route groups in laravel 5.4 i cant run php artisan serv and get this error

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

this is my code

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    $this->get('/panel','PanelController@index');
    $this->resource('/articles','ArticleController@index');
});
```

and i create Admin directory in Controllers but i cant run `php artisan serve` and i get this error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>         syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ar you sure you are using Laravel 5.4?

Try the following structure which has been tested in Laravel 5.4:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/panel','PanelController@index');
    Route::resource('/articles','ArticleController');
});
```

The only reason your route structure would not work is if you are not using the correct version of Laravel for your syntax.